# How to print a range of character in unix using cut and grep?

Tags: linux, unix, grep, cut

I can print block of characters using (`cut -d`) specifying delimiter.

```
# grep -i access.log| grep ' 500 '| cut -d\- -f1
```

But how can I print characters after specific pattern "`address=tel%3A%2B`"

For example: how to print the entire phone numbers in this file?

```
begining of the line address=tel%3A%2B416xxxxxxx rest of the log
begining of the line address=tel%3A%2B647xxxxxxx rest of the log
begining of the line address=tel%3A%2B519xxxxxxx rest of the log
```

...

Comment: I think `sed` is the tool to use. You can specify a capturing regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -e 's,.*address=tel%3A%2B\([^ ]\+\).*,\1,g' <<EOF                          
begining of the line address=tel%3A%2B416xxxxxxx rest of the log                
begining of the line address=tel%3A%2B647xxxxxxx rest of the log                
begining of the line address=tel%3A%2B519xxxxxxx rest of the log                
EOF
```

Output:

```
416xxxxxxx
647xxxxxxx
519xxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried `cut -c` to print characters with specific position in the line and it works since most of the lines follows identical pattern.
Position of the line starts from 1.

```
# grep -i test.log| grep ' 500 '|cut -c1-5
```

here 1: is the starting position of character.

here 5: position of last character to print.

so for example if :

```
#cat test.log
this is address=tel%3A%2B416xxxxxxx
this is address=tel%3A%2B647xxxxxxx
this is address=tel%3A%2B519xxxxxxx

#cut -c26-36 test.log 
416xxxxxxx
647xxxxxxx
519xxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a job for grep and/or cut, it's a job for sed or awk:

```
$ sed 's/.*address=tel%3A%2B\([^ ]*\).*/\1/' file
416xxxxxxx
647xxxxxxx
519xxxxxxx

$ awk '{gsub(/.*address=tel%3A%2B| .*/,"")}1' file
416xxxxxxx
647xxxxxxx
519xxxxxxx
```

Comment: can you explain this a bit please. I can't figure out the / \ and * how it should be set up to print me the spesific part of the log I need.

Comment: The scripts DO print the specific part of the log you need, just run them on your posted sample input. I'm sorry but this is absolutely fundamental sed and awk, you need to do a little reading before trying to do any scripting in UNIX and people explaining the basics one example at at time is not a good way to learn. I recommend Bash Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson for the basics of shell scripting (includes all you need to know about sed) and then Effective Awk Programming 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to really learn how to use awk well.